# Handle delimiter in text of column in source file for External table (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, csv, external, delimiter

I have a flat source file (.csv fromat), fields are delimited by comma(,) and records are delimited by newline.
But there is a scenario, where one of the fields itself contains comma within it.
It is some kind of description which user puts and this field can contain any number of commas.
So how can we handle this situation, so that we can access the file through external table in Oracle 10g?

Do we need to ask the source system to send the file with different delimiter (which I feel as the last option, as I thought of handling it at our end only); or is there some other option as well.

Comment: Are those fields enclosed in quotes?

Comment: No, they are plain text without any quotes.

Comment: Then tell your source to send you valid CSV files. What they sent you is ambiguous, can't be processed without heuristics.

Comment: Can we replace those extra comma(s) with some other special character using Unix?

Comment: How can you know which one to replace?

Comment: Mat is absolutely right.  It is the duty of the sending system to produce data in a loadable format.  It is the right of the loading system to specify that format.  Of course this is a political problem not a technical one.

Comment: We calculate the number of commas present in each line and remove the extra commas. Suppose, there are 10 fields and the text description is at 5th position. And the number of commas in a line is 12, that means total 3 comma are extra. Using sed command we will remove/replace commas present at 5,6 and 7th position. But this will be unnecessary effort.

Comment: And that only "works" if there is only one text field. And you can't tell if you actually got it right or if the data has other quality issues and you're about to load total garbage in your database. The only sane approach is to get  sanely formatted input.

Comment: Ok, will do that. Thanks!!!